# Can I use .dotenv library as HTML script imports only without npm or node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, import, dotenv

Is there a way to use dotenv library as an import (e.g from CDN) only in a HTML script tag or .js file?
I mean without node or npm require or imports.. Otherwise I would have to use something like webpack and I just want to test it quickly on a HTML page...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No.

`dotenv` is a backend tool for getting variables set in a `.env` file. If you are using `.env` files for public use, that is misusing what the point of environment variables are for. Maybe try just using a `filename.json` or `fileame.yml` file for public consumption, but `.env` files are only used for secret things, like API keys, database passwords, etc.

Comment: but if I use filename.json its also publicly visible, even if I have sensitive information there, right? Is there any other way to use sensitive information on client in Frontend without exposing it directly? (e.g in browser?)

Comment: There is no such thing as sensitive information if you send it to the client. The browser's tools, like Inspect Element, the Console, the `Debugger;` command, the Network tab, etc. makes any information that is sent to the client accessible. The only way to keep this private is by sending requests to a backend api, like a RESTful API or a GraphQL API.

Comment: but if I use tools like browserify, I could theoretically use npm with node, and import it in a .js file and from there call .env right? but I would probably have to upload the .env file also to git if I wanted to use it from client then I guess.. The problem that I have is, that I am hosting a website from github pages... and I dont know how to use / store sensitive database information and pass that to the client, I want to run different functionality from github pages only.. is there a way to pass environment variables from github to my page maybe?

Comment: Hosting will GitHub pages is only for static sites, meaning the content is pre-compiled and isn't responsively server-side-rendered, and doesn't have a database or any way to use a database directly. You'd need to host a database and a backend through nodejs (maybe use the expressjs framework) and query that API and use `.env` on the serverside. What kind of environment variables are you wanting to use?

Comment: I essentially only want to use Firebase Realtime DB config in my .env or otherwise, maybe it works also with email /pw login on firebase server-side with a token that gets passed back, maybe thats sufficient to do database requests, so I wouldn't need any .env or config environment, right?